# Issue regarding caching image links from firebase storage using service-worker pre-cache?

Tags: cors, firebase-storage, progressive-web-apps, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

I have the following code for a service worker that pre-cache images, the issue is other images links work like charm they get cached with no problem, what so ever but when it comes to firebase image links they just don't get cached, even if I the set cache control to

> public,max-age=31536000

[image]

no I am kind of lost why does links that are not coming from firebase gets cached and firebase don't is it some bucked setting that are causing this ? or should setup my hosting header with some extra setting ?

here is my code

```js
// L2 Public folder and external links...
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open('pre-cache-png')
      .then((cache) => cache.add('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject/imglink.png'))
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error caching image:', error))
  );
});
```

if I use an image link hosted on other platform I can see it instantly get cached, I also disabled all the rules, yet still nothing..

my firebase hosting header looks like the following

```js
 "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "headers": [
      {
      // serves cache.mainfest mime type as "text/cache-mainfest"
        "source": "/cache.mainfest",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "text/cache-mainfest"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

also in my console it get the following error

> Access to fetch at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject/imglink.png' from origin 'https://app.myproject.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

also for the record run time cache works fine, but pre-cache is erroring out..